# Check for a prime number using recursive helper function

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, primes, primality-test

I am trying to check if a number is prime using recursion. I was required to use a recursive helper function, but I am not sure how I should implement it.

I think I know the algorithm, but I've never tried to use a recursive helper function in Racket. This is my current thoughts:

1. See if n is divisible by `i = 2`
2. Set `i = i + 1`
3. If `i^2 <= n` continue.
4. If no values of `i` evenly divided `n`, then it must be prime.

This is what I have so far...

```
(define (is_prime n)
  (if (<= n 1)
      #f
      (if (= (modulo n 2) 0)
          #f

)
```

What would be a good approach using a recursive helper function??

Thanks!

Comment: A small optimization is possible: once you check the case n = 2, we can skip all the even numbers by starting from 3 and adding 2 at each iteration.

Comment: Move the incrementing step last, and note that point 3 is the negation of point 4, and a solution becomes more visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a helper simply means that you should split your program in smaller parts, and possibly encapsulate loops with extra parameters in separate procedures - and in Scheme loops are frequently implemented via recursive calls. One (naïve) way to implement the `is_prime` procedure would be:

```
(define (is_prime n)
  (cond ((<= n 1) #f)
        ((= n 2) #t)
        ((= (modulo n 2) 0) #f)
        (else (check 3 n))))

; recursive helper
(define (check i n)
  (cond ((> (* i i) n) #t)
        ((= (modulo n i) 0) #f)
        (else (check (+ i 2) n))))
```

There are many ways to implement this procedure, and many possible optimizations; the above should be enough get you started.

Comment: Aha, I see now... Thanks a lot for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (isPrimeHelper x k)
  (if (= x k) #t
  (if (= (remainder x k) 0) #f
     (isPrimeHelper x (+ k 1)))))

(define ( isPrime x )
  (cond
    (( = x 0 ) #f)
    (( = x 1 ) #f)
    (( = x 2 ) #t)
     ( else (isPrimeHelper x 2 ) )))
```

I prefer this version.

Comment: It's easier to understand, for sure - but I have a coupe of comments: `0` and `1` are not primes. And this is way more inefficient, there's no need to check up until `x` equals `k`, it's enough to check until `x > sqrt(k)`